# Intermittent connection to Azure-devops. Unable to push code to the repo

Tags: azure-devops

I use Azure repository for managing code and I have not been very lucky
with checking in code and pushing code. I would get one error or the other.

Here are some of the errors I get

fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/mydevops/myStartup/_git/myStartup/':
OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to dev.azure.com:xxx

Failed to push the branch to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.

Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Branch feature/445-create-unit-test does not exist.
Commit changes locally and then push.

I tried to check in a branch and it got checked in but when It was time to push, I was not able
to push. Here is what I got. I got a message to run the command below

git push --set-upstream origin feature/445-create-unit-test

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this problem, in my case it was IPv6 issue.

Try this:

1. Open command line and do `ping dev.azure.com` - if the IP address is IPv6 (something like `2620:1ec:21::20`), then it might be the problem.
2. configure Windows to [prefer v4 over v6](https://gavindraper.com/2018/05/03/Setting-Windows-To-Prefer-IPV4-Over-IPV6/):

   ```
   netsh int ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 51
   ```

Alternatively, you might [disable IPv6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows#using-the-network-properties-gui-to-disable-ipv6-is-not-supported) alltogether.

Comment: after hours of researching and battling this issue, this was the fix I needed! Wish I came across it sooner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

qbik's answer was a godsend, thank you!  The error I was getting was

> Recv failure: Connection was reset

However this has gotten a little more complicated to fix with Windows 11.  See the following link:  https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000160803-prioritising-ipv4-over-ipv6-on-windows-10-and-11.  Basically, you have 2 options.

1. Modify or create the following registry entry, and reboot:

> ```
> Location: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters
> Key: DisabledComponents
> Type: REG_DWORD
> Value: 0x20
> ```

2. Assuming you haven't changed your ipv6 policies from the default, run the following series of commands:

> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 50 0
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::1/128 40 1
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::/0 30 2
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy 2002::/16 20 3
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy 2001::/32 5 5
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy fc00::/7 3 13
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy fec0::/10 1 11
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy 3ffe::/16 1 12
>
> netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::/96 1 4